# Is there any way to prevent the ios from killing my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, jailbreak

My app is jailbroken and I don't have to submit it to the app store.The problem is the ios kills my app after 2 or 3 hours.I have used the static analyzer from xcode and removed all memory leaks.I have even installed a memory monitor.There is atleast 300 mb of free memory when the ios kills my app.Is there any way to prevent the ios from killing my app?

Comment: Maybe check the crash log, see the real reason why your app is being killed. Not necessarily excessive memory, it could be an unhandled exception

Comment: @gerrytan its not an exception.The crash says received memory warning.Failed to save crash report to blah blah blah

Comment: Are you talking about your app being killed while it's still in the foreground, or being killed in the background (after user has pressed home button, etc.)?

Comment: My app always runs in the background

Comment: Is it a Launch Daemon, or a normal app with a UI?

Comment: the app does not have a UI

Comment: But, how is it **started**?  Do you have an icon on the home screen, or have you installed a .plist under `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` to make it start automatically when the phone boots?  And, is it installed in `/Applications/`, or `/var/mobile/Applications/*/`?

Comment: i hava installled a .plist

Comment: You might [also take a look at this answer, if you're concerned about a memory issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2915477/119114)

Comment: @Nate Dude Can you help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653779/how-do-i-use-this-class-in-my-project I would really appreciate your help

Comment: You can also may be interested to see a discussion about daemons and background apps here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025174/pull-notification-locally-on-jailbroken-device/15454926#15454926

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try playing a silent audio file in a loop using `AVAudioPlayer`.  iOS won't shut down your app if it's playing.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24

Also SO: [How to handle background audio playing while iOS device is locked or on another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429204/how-to-handle-background-audio-playing-while-ios-device-is-locked-or-on-another)

Comment: how sure are you about this?

Comment: @iOsBoy: I noticed a few apps have audio files with no sound. Perhaps they're used for this purpose.