# how to create app working as background daemon with no front end for jailbreak iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios6, jailbreak

i need to create an app for the jailbreak iPhone with ios6.The problem is it should always be working in background like a 'service' with no GUI.
i have saw some tutorial(Chris Alvares daemon) for demon creation but all are for ios4 and using toolchain is there any updated way to active this.

Comment: The technique in Chris' tutorial still works (iOS 6), and you can use the normal Xcode tool to build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Nate's answer on this question: [pull notification locally on jailbroken device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025174/pull-notification-locally-on-jailbroken-device)

It has excellent description of building a deamon.